# why is loop writing to database infinite times ignore loop rules to just do it once?

Tags: php, json, loops

GOAL:

To run a continuous loop through a function returning json results adding new results to a database table and doing some things when it finds a new result while ignoring old results. As the wallet recieves transactions the json is updated and as its updated i want to be able to ad the new transactions to the database.

PROBLEM:

the loop gets out of control. it writes the last transaction data an infinite number of times instead of just once. it should write it once and then next time it goes through the loop, the last transaction (the previously new transaction) should now be considered old and ignored, and any "new" transactions should go through the loop and be added (but it seems to just keep seeing the last one as new and keep writing it over and over again).

```
   do {
    
        ## incoming transactions from wallet
        $incoming   = json_decode(transaction_list($wallet_id), true);
        
    
        ## incoming transactions database 
        $in_rows    = $db->run('SELECT * FROM incoming_transactions WHERE id IS NOT NULL');
    
    
        ## start listning for new transactions 
        foreach ($incoming as $in_tx => $in_data) {
    
            ## get transaction id
            $in_id      = $in_data['id'];
    
            ## get the transaction amount
            $in_amount  = $in_data['amount']['quantity'];
    
            ## by default we assume that the transaction is new
            $old_transaction = false;
                
    
            ## check the database for past transactions 
            foreach ($in_rows as $row) {
              
                    
                    $db_id = $row['id'];
    
                    ## if the database has the same id as the transaction id in the ledger
                    ## then its an old transaction
                                
                    if ($db_id == $in_id) {
    
                        
                        $old_transaction = true;
                    
            
                    }
                
                    ## if there are old transactions
                    ## dont do anything, only act on new transactions
                    
                    if ($old_transaction == true) {
                        
                        ## wait for a new transaction
                                        
                    }
    
    
                    ## if the transaction is new..

                    else if ($old_transaction == false) {
                        
                        
                        ## first, make sure they sent at least 2 ADA
    
                        if ($in_amount < 2000000) {
    
                            ## if less than 2 ada is recieved
                            ## do nothing.                          
                        
                        }   
                        
                        else {
    
    
                            ## if they sent at least 2 ADA then we can continue..
                        
                            // incoming transactions data
                            $in_amount_unit     = $in_data['amount']['unit'];
                            $in_input_address   = $in_data['inputs'][0]['address'];
                            $in_wallet_id       = substr($in_input_address, 7, 10);
    
                            ## setup return transaction containing meta data
    
                            ## determine how many random numbers were going to need to send back.
                            
                            ## for now this is set to 1.
                                            
                            $how_many = 1;
                            
                            ## generate metadata
    
                            $metadata           = json_encode(generate_random($in_wallet_id, $how_many));
                            $meta               = json_decode($metadata, true);
                            
                            $meta_number        = $meta['6879']['RandomNumber'][0]['Number'];
                            $meta_signature_1   = $meta['6879']['RandomNumber'][0]['Signature1'];
                            $meta_signature_2   = $meta['6879']['RandomNumber'][0]['Signature2'];
                            $meta_id            = $meta['6879']['RandomNumber'][0]['Id'];
    
    
                            ## do the transaction to send the metadata
                            $payment_address    = $in_input_address;
                            
## send 1 ada back with the metadata
$payment_amount     = 1000000;
    
                            #$outgoing = transaction_create($wallet_id, $passphrase, $payment_address, $payment_amount, $metadata);
    
                            ## update the databases with incoming and outgoing transactions
    
                            ## update new incoming transactions
                            
                            
                            ## update the database with incoming transactions
                            $db->insert('incoming_transactions', [
                                "amount_quantity"   =>  $in_amount, 
                                "amount_unit"       =>  $in_amount_unit,
                                "input_address"     =>  $in_input_address,
                                "id"                =>  $in_id,
                                "wallet_id"         =>  $in_wallet_id # key
                            ]); 
    
                            echo "### TRANSACTION: INCOMING: " . $in_id . "\n";
                            #echo "### TRANSACTION: OUTGOING: " . $out_id . "\n";
     
                        
                        }
                    
                    }
                }
            }
    
    
    }
    
    while(true);
```

Comment: Removing all that extra whitespace would go a long way towards the readbility of your code.

Comment: If you have control over the other code that writes to `incoming_transactions`, then I would suggest adopting a different architecture. Like some type of messaging design (e.g. IPC, WebSocket, webhook/callback), instead of polling forever.

Comment: @RoAchterberg i do not control what writes the data to the incoming transaction json.